# Python - print the line pointed by error message

Tags: python, json, string

To load a json, I use the `json.loads()` method with a `try/except` block to get where the error has been occured if it fail.

I am getting errors, in the form:

```sh
Expecting object: line 1 column 14117248 (char 14117247)
```

I am asking if there is a way to get the line/char pointed by this error.

Is there a way in python that return the `line X column Y` from a string?

Comment: That is a **very long line**. Of course you can print this; you have the coordinates in the exception message; parse it, then split out the string. But it sounds as if your string contains a trailing comma.

Comment: ah! ok, can you explain to me what `line 1 column 14117248` mean?

Comment: And, what is a wrong with a ` trailing comma`? Thanks

Comment: Your input string contains lines (delimited by `\n`). The first line has at least 14117247 characters. The parser expected the start of another object after that, at column 14117248.

Comment: A common way for that error to occur for there to be a comma before that position, but not the start of a new object after it. `[0,]` would give you that error at column 4 for example, because `]` is not a new object, but the end of the list instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Python 3.5 onwards, decoding can raise an [`JSONDecodeError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError). This exception contains a few extra attributes, use those to print out some context. I'd limit this to a small string. Your sample input string has at least 14117247 characters on the first line, probably because your input contains no line separators at all; it is probably not all that helpful to print *all* those characters:

```
import json

try:
    json.loads(some_string)
except json.JSONDecodeError as err:
    # grab a reasonable section, say 40 characters.
    start, stop = max(0, err.pos - 20), err.pos + 20
    snippet = err.doc[start:stop]
    print(err)
    print('... ' if start else '', snippet, ' ...' if stop < len(err.doc) else '', sep="")
    print('^'.rjust(21 if not start else 25))
```

This outputs 40 characters of context (with ellipsis to indicate where we cut the string short) and adds a `^` caret underneath the indicated position:

```py
>>> import random, json
>>> some_string = json.dumps([{"foo": "bar"}] * 1_000_000)
>>> error_pos = random.randrange(len(some_string))
>>> error_pos = some_string.find(",", error_pos)  # to avoid injecting an error inside a string
>>> some_string = some_string[:error_pos] + "!" + some_string[error_pos:]
>>> try:
...     json.loads(some_string)
... except json.JSONDecodeError as err:
...     # grab a reasonable section, say 40 characters.
...     start, stop = max(0, err.pos - 20), err.pos + 20
...     snippet = err.doc[start:stop]
...     print(err)
...     print('... ' if start else '', snippet, ' ...' if stop < len(err.doc) else '', sep="")
...     print('^'.rjust(21 if not start else 25))
...
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 14153440 (char 14153439)
... ar"}, {"foo": "bar"}!, {"foo": "bar"}, { ...
                        ^
```

In Python 3.4 and earlier, a `ValueError` exception is raised. You can parse the  *message* (the `exception.args[0]` value) for clues, but this requires manual string parsing. See the [`errmsg()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/json/decoder.py#l33); reverse its formatting when parsing.

For this specific case however (where a value is expected), you'll need 3.4 or newer to get a line and column indicator; before 3.4 the best the module could do was give you the unhelpful message [*No JSON object could be decoded*](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/json/decoder.py#l382).

Comment: Maybe this has changed since 3.5, but `err.doc[start, stop]` didn't work for me.  I had to use `err.doc[start:stop]` in 3.7.

Comment: @MarcelWilson: oops, yes, that's a typo in my answer. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, no. At least in Python 2.7. `loads` does not provide any means for customizing how it behaves on errors.

```
try:
    value, end = scan_once(s, end)
except StopIteration:
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting object", s, end))
```

But you can parse the location from the error message to read the line from your input. The error format can be either `{0}: line {1} column {2} (char {3})` or `{0}: line {1} column {2} - line {3} column {4} (char {5} - {6})`.

Comment: The exception shows that they are using the Python 3 `json` module, which *does* carry this context.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it's not obvious for me. The exception class is not given, but the message is nearly the same.

Comment: The Python 2 error message is simply *No JSON object could be decoded*. Compare that to the error given in the OP, and you'll see that that message obviously gives more detailed information.

Comment: You don't need to read the message from the input. Just catch the exception and parse `exception.args[0]`; but you'll need Python 3.4 for that message to contain anything useful. Or upgrade to 3.5 and pull the information from the extra attributes.

Comment: That is not true for 2.7. Take a look at the source code here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/json/decoder.py

Comment: Right, so the case discussed here hits the `StopIteration` exception at the end of that module.  Interesting to see there are more useful error messages for some of the cases.

Comment: Compare this to the [3.5 version](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/json/decoder.py) where there is a rich exception object instead.